# Why action method call twice from Firefox while same call from google-come method call only once. Network call only single

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts 2 in my web application with tiles also.I get data from simple get method from my action class. On page load in Firefox browser my get method execute twice while in network only single action call and in google chrome browser this method execute only single. What is going wrong in my web application.

Comment: `google-come` alone earned you a downvote

Comment: When i use <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 in jsp then my action method call twice